# "Add Service Reference" Generates No Proxy Methods

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I want to connect to this web service, 
http://aye.comp.nus.edu.sg/parsCit/wing.nus.wsdl

So I clicked Add Service reference and pointed it to the path, but I can't figure out how to invoke the service.  My Reference.cs class contains only this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.261
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I think it didn't generate any methods.  What should I try?

Comment: Did you see any errors/warnings in the visual studio's ErrorList window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am looking at this through a mobile phone, so maybe that is the problem, but the wsdl doesn't not contain any method definitions. That would be why you are not seeing any methods...there are none.